# Banner Ads (libgdx in Android studio)

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, banner-ads

I have a very difficult question for the community.
I'm trying to insert a banner in a state of my application, but it is not the first one that opens at the beginning. 
In my application there is a initial screen and when I press in a hitbox, I go to the other screen with the banner, so in the following code **TestPubb()** is the second state.

This is the AndroidLauncher:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
private static final String TAG ="AndroidLauncher";
protected AdView adView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    View gameView = initializeForView(new TestPubb(), config);
    layout.addView(gameView);


    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Ad Loaded...");
        }
    });
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");


    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    builder.addTestDevice("5845100B11B77FFC8C7AC54BD59AD27C");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    adView.loadAd(builder.build());

    setContentView(layout);


}

}
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't you forgot to initialize the Mobile Ads SDK before loading a banner?
This should be done once:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
...
```

In more details described [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#initialize_mobileads)

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing visibility of `AdView` by overriding `onAdLoaded()` method of  an `AdListener` that forces the ad-view to draw itself once the ad finished loading. Something like:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            System.out.println("ad banner finished loading!");
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }        
    });
```

Google recommend to use `MobileAds.initialize(XXXXX)` but it is not necessary.

The Mobile Ads SDK take a few milliseconds to initialize itself so Mobile Ad SDK have provided `initialize(..)` method to call it way before you even call your first ad. Once that is done, there would not be any added load time for your first request. If you do not call this, then your very first AdRequest would take a few milliseconds more as it first needs to initialize itself.